# How to solve DF-CPA2-07 PlayMarket error?

Tags: android, google-play

I get DF-CPA2-07 error, when I try to buy item in Android App.

```
Error
Error while retrieving information from server.
[DF-CPA2-07]
```

How to solve it?

Comment: How is this question related to programming?

Comment: I believe it relates to play market administration or device or google account problem.

Comment: So, nothing related to programming.

Comment: Der, any ideas? I already try to clear cache in all google apps in device.

Comment: @DerGolem - no, a factory reset is probably unwarranted.  If the user doesn't have much on the device it could be tried as an experiment, but it's a big step with no real expectation of success.