# in-app purchase error [DF-CPA2-07x8]

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchase

I have a problem on developing subscription plan.
Doesn't find the answer from
[How to solve DF-CPA2-07 PlayMarket error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30217545/how-to-solve-df-cpa2-07-playmarket-error?answertab=active#tab-top)

It could work on first purchase when no plan is subscribed but fail on upgrading one plan to another. Got the error `[DF-CPA2-07x8]` from Google server. Clear data and cache for **Google Store** App doesn't work. Need some advice, thanks

Answer (score 0):

This means the process took too long when doing the upgrade and timed out. It is a problem at the Google Play end. If it is happening frequently and repeatably for you then you should contact the Google Play Console support team and ask them to report it to the Google developers. They will collect some more information from you, and be able to look at exactly the request that is causing the problem. They will be interested in the exact error code, the app, and the account that was making the purchase, as well as the logs from your device.

You can contact support under the help menu in the Google Play console.

Comment: This error happens every time for me upgrade the plan :(. I have contacted Google Play console support and waiting for their further investigation. Thank you, Nick.